# Restructure Datatable in an efficient way

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to generate dynamic caml query, and because of requirement, my system allow user to group searching condition

**User Input**

```
Group | FieldName | LogicOperator | Value | AndOrTag
------+-----------+---------------+-------+----------
1     |  TITLE    |  Eq           | 2     | And
NULL  |  TITLE    |  Eq           | 1     | Or
1     |  TITLE    |  Eq           | 1     | And
2     |  TITLE    |  Eq           | 3     | NULL
```

Table above is my datatable, because of requirements, I am required to sort my table to below output

**Expected output**

```
Group | FieldName | LogicOperator | Value | AndOrTag
------+-----------+---------------+-------+----------
1     |  TITLE    |  Eq           | 2     | And 
1     |  TITLE    |  Eq           | 1     | And
2     |  TITLE    |  Eq           | 3     | NULL
NULL  |  TITLE    |  Eq           | 1     | Or
```

System is limit user to select up to 2 group only. either null, 1 or 2.

To restructure, what can i think off is

create 4 data table

datatable1 for Group 1

datatable2 for Group 2

datatable3 for null

datatable4 for All

first of all, i will loop original input value

if record is belong to group 1, then insert to datatable1

if record is belong to group 2, then insert to datatable2

if record is belong to no group, then insert to datatable3

once looping is done

i will pump data to datatable4 by sequences

pump datatable1 data into datatable4

pump datatable2 data into datatable4

pump datatable3 data into datatable4

then i will get my expected output

However is that any other way can achieve my objective? Because the method that I think of is not very efficient! Please advice

Comment: Why not just sort by the `Group ` and get your required output ??

Comment: @CoderofCode i did try to use dataview to sort by group, however the output is not what i want, it sort others column as well ~

Comment: How about just add a row number column, then sort with group then row number

Comment: @Eric i buy ur idea, you inspired me !!